# How to change WP mysql user/pass from localhost to server?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I just created WP site on my localhost machine and I am about to upload it to production server. Both environments run on the same OS with same libraries and php versions, but the password I set up for my local mysql install is different from the production server. So, I was thinking about uploading the entire WP file and once in the prod, I could alter the `wp-config.php` and changing the db, but this seems unmanageable in the long term if I have to pull the code to local again or migrate to another server ...

so, my question is how is this done?

Comment: Are you saying that you want to upload all the sql tables from the develop server to the production server? except the user table, which is different between the development server and the production server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have separate database parameters for both 'localhost' and 'production' servers in 'wp-config.php' like below.

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']=="localhost") //change if local server name is different
{
    $db_name='local_db_name';
    $db_username='local_db_username';
    $db_password='local_db_password';
    $db_host='local_db_host';
}
else // production server database credentials
{
    $db_name='production_db_name';
    $db_username='production_db_username';
    $db_password='production_db_password';
    $db_host='production_db_host';      
}

// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //
/** The name of the database for WordPress */
define('DB_NAME', $db_name);

/** MySQL database username */
define('DB_USER', $db_username);

/** MySQL database password */
define('DB_PASSWORD', $db_password);

/** MySQL hostname */
define('DB_HOST', $db_host);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do it this way too, except, sometimes you'll need to check against `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

And there's another thing - to sync between the local and production servers, (in most cases) you don't need the root files synced too.
Just the contend of `/wp-content/` folder (plugins, themes and uploads specifically).
And of course, the database content.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that you are exposing sensitive credentials in wp-config.php.

Comment: I agree but this is the WordPress default, WordPress itself saves the credentials over here. Question is how to use same 'wp-config.php' and not about higher-end security.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handle this is to use server environment variables:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv

I highly recommend that you **do not store your password or any other private information directly in your wordpress wp-config file** like some others have mentioned.

Your local setup will have environment variables like this:

```
SetEnv DB_USER mylocaldbuser
SetEnv DB_NAME mylocaldbname
SetEnv DB_HOST mylocaldbhost
SetEnv DB_PASS mylocaldbpass
```

Then your production server will have its own set of environment variables:

```
SetEnv DB_USER myproddbuser
SetEnv DB_NAME myproddbname
SetEnv DB_HOST myproddbhost
SetEnv DB_PASS myproddbpass
```

Finally, your wp-config.php file will look like this:

```
define('DB_NAME',      $_SERVER['DB_NAME']);
define('DB_USER',      $_SERVER['DB_USER']);
define('DB_PASSWORD',  $_SERVER['DB_PASS']);
define('DB_HOST',      $_SERVER['DB_HOST']);
```

By setting things up this way, your wp-config.php file will not change across your different environments so you'll never have to worry about editing it each time you deploy to prod. You'll also be erring on the side of caution by not exposing any sensitive information in your wp-config, which is in a public directory.

Comment: this looks like the better one, but setting env does not automatically fille `$_SERVER` variable with data. Did you mean `$_ENV`?

Comment: Hmm you should be able to use the apache SetEnv directive to set $_SERVER variables in your apache config.

Answer (score 1):

Use the plugin [All-in-One WP Migration](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

- Install it on your local set up and the production server.
- Create an export file from your local WP install.
- Import it on your production WP install and your data will be exported properly.

Please note that I am assuming you have WordPress installed on your production server. If that is not the case you first have to install WordPress over there and then follow the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Phpmyadmin, choose your DB then click on export tab
there you can export data in your desired format then import it back using import tab.

in case of pages or other filesystem data, you can use filezilla or other ftp tool.

Answer (score 1):

How I would do this is as follows:

```
//::1 is localhost on servers using ipv6, 127.0.0.1 is for ipv4
$localIpList      = ['::1', '127.0.0.1'];
$databasePassword = 'productionPassword';

if (in_array($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], $localIpList)) {
    $databasePassword = 'localDevPassword';
}
```

Doing it this way makes it pretty easily maintainable, and SERVER_ADDR is fairly reliable, using an array with in_array() makes it easy to add IPs in the future if say you use a different dev server (other than localhost).

Answer (score -1):

You can change the password for a particular user by adding this code in functions.php

wp_set_password( $password, $user_id ) ;

[source](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password)

**Note: Delete the above code once you resetted to your current password else this code will be executed whenever a user visits your website.**

You can change Username from Database

Comment: He is asking to change mysql password not wordpress user's password.

Answer (score -3):

You can change your user/pass from the database directly. Here are the steps,

- open the **wp_users** table in database.
- select the user you want to edit and click on **edit** link.
- update password with **MD5** and user_email with your email address.
- Now try to login with the updated credentials.

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: This would mean both prod/local mysql DBs would have same user, pass .. but they dont in my example